# Django how to pass clicked on link text to a URL on another HTML page showing static images?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have table of tickers on one HTML page, and four charts displayed on another HTML page. These charts come from my static/images folder full of hundreds of images named by each ETF's benchmark index ticker. If I click the ETF ticker "PSCD" in the first row of the table, how can it be linked to another HTML page named charts.html which shows four charts whose filenames contain the ETF's benchmark index ticker, example: `chart1/S6COND.jpg`, `chart2/S6COND.jpg`, `chart3/S6COND.jpg`, `chart4/S6COND.jpg`. <- In this example, I hardcoded S6COND.jpg into the link, and it works...but I need it to be dynamically tied to the index ticker of whatever etf ticker row I click on in the table. The index ticker for each ETF for each row in the table is included in my models.py which you can see below.

In the charts.html code example below, I hardcoded S6COND into the image tag but I want this dynamically linked.

[image]

Below you will see my table.html page showing my table from above. Next is the charts.html where I would like the etf_ticker that was clicked in that table to be entered into the image tags such as `<img src="{% static 'myapp/images/chart1_S6COND.jpg' %}" alt="chart1"/></div>` where you see I have hardcoded "S6COND" into the image tag. But I need this to be dynamic, from which you click on the link in table.html, and it gets inserted into the image tag in charts.html.

table.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ETF Table</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'myapp/css/table_style.css' %}">
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <table id="table" class="table table-dark table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th data-sortable="true">ETF Ticker</th>
      <th>ETF Name</th>
      <th>Index Name</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    {% if d %}
    {% for i in d %}
     <tr>
        <td><a href="{% url 'myapp:charts' %}" target="_blank">{{i.etf_ticker}}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'myapp:charts' %}" target="_blank">{{i.etf_name}}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'myapp:charts' %}" target="_blank">{{i.index_name}}</a></td>
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
  $('#table').DataTable({
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "lengthMenu": [ [20, 50, 100 -1], [20, 50, 100, "All"] ],
    "iDisplayLength": 20,
    bInfo: false,
    responsive: true,
    order: [[4, 'desc']],
  });
  </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

charts.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Charts</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'myapp/css/charts_style.css' %}">
    <style type="text/css">
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav" href="{% url 'myapp:index' %}">Home</a></li><br><br>
    <li><a class="nav" href="{% url 'myapp:table' %}">Table</a></li><br>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'myapp/images/chart1_S6COND.jpg' %}" alt="chart1"/></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'myapp/images/chart2_S6COND.jpg' %}" alt="chart2"/></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'myapp/images/chart3_S6COND.jpg' %}" alt="chart3"/></div>
    <div class="box"><img src="{% static 'myapp/images/chart4_S6COND.jpg' %}" alt="chart4"/></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import ChartView

app_name = 'myapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('table/', views.table, name='table'),
    path('charts/', ChartView.as_view(), name='charts'),
]
```

models.py

```py
from django.db import models


class Table(models.Model):
    etf_ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    etf_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    index_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    index_ticker = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import Table


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def table(request):
    data = Table.objects.all().values()
    context = {'d': data}
    return render(request, 'table.html', context)


class ChartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'charts.html'
```

Comment: Are these questions for a project from some online course? I swear I just answered a Django links question that had the same picture attached xD

Comment: No, I am asking a different question concerning the same application, that's why it looks very similar. The answer you gave was great, but it shows just one .jpg image. This question asks how to link to another HTML page showing not just one chart, but four, all selected from static/images based on the ticker symbol. I would've just asked this question, but hadn't thought of this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer after several days and many hours. Now, when I click on any link in any row, the next html page shows 4 charts of data corresponding to the etf_ticker of that table row.

I had to change the following:

In `table.html`, didn't need `{% if d %}` and added `i.id` to the href tag.

```
{% for i in d %}
<tr>
    <td><a href="{% url 'myapp:charts' i.id %}" target="_blank">{{i.etf_ticker}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'myapp:charts' i.id %}" target="_blank">{{i.etf_name}}</a></td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'myapp:charts' i.id %}" target="_blank">{{i.index_name}}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In `models.py`, I had to add database fields to hold the URL of each etf_ticker's 4 charts to be displayed on charts.html. After changing the model, I deleted all files except **init** in the migrations folder. I then ran `python manage.py makemigrations myapp` and then `python manage.py migrate`. This created a new database from scratch where I re-uploaded my data into.

```
from django.db import models


class Table(models.Model):
    etf_ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    etf_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    index_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    index_ticker = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    chart1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    chart2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    chart3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    chart4 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

In `views,py`, replaced `ChartView(TemplateView)` with:

```
def charts_(request, pk):
    charts = Table.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {'charts': charts}
    return render(request, 'charts.html', context)
```

In `urls.py`, I had to add `<int:pk>` to the charts path and remove ChartView and in `urlpatterns`, changed to `views.charts_` with an underscore to prevent any naming conflicts between the function name and variable names also named charts.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'myapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('table/', views.table, name='table'),
    path('charts/<int:pk>', views.charts_, name='charts'),
]
```

Finally, in `charts.html`, change the source tag urls to this:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <img class="grid-item" src="{% static 'myapp/images/' %}{{charts.chart1}}" alt="chart1"/>
    <img class="grid-item" src="{% static 'myapp/images/' %}{{charts.chart2}}" alt="chart2"/>
    <img class="grid-item" src="{% static 'myapp/images/' %}{{charts.chart3}}" alt="chart3"/>
    <img class="grid-item" src="{% static 'myapp/images/' %}{{charts.chart4}}" alt="chart4"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Modify the path for the charts page (to one that accepts a parameter) and pass in the ticker to this path. You can use that to filter content.

In your `urls.py` modify the path to charts:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import ChartView

app_name = 'forecast'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('table/', views.table, name='table'),
    path('charts/<str:ticker>', ChartView.as_view(), name='charts')
]
```

In `table.html` modify the links to the charts page:

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp:charts' i.index_ticker %}" target="_blank">
```

In your `views.py`, modify `ChartView` to accept a parameter:

```
class ChartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'charts.html'
    
    def get(self, request, ticker):
        return render(request, self.template_name, { 'ticker': ticker })
```

And in `charts.html`, edit the source tag of the image in the following manner:

```
<img src="{% static 'myapp/images/chart4_'|add:ticker|add:'.jpg' %}" alt="chart4"/>
```

Comment: That generates error:

Signature of method 'ChartView.get()' does not match signature of the base method in class 'TemplateView'

TypeError at /myapp/charts/
get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ticker'

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/charts/
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ticker'
Exception Location: path\django\views\generic\base.py, line 101, in dispatch

Comment: I've made a modification to the chartView class. Try that and let me know if it works

Comment: I feel like we're close but here is the error that comes up: VariableDoesNotExist at /myapp/charts/
Failed lookup for key [ticker] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}]
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/charts/
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: VariableDoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
Failed lookup for key [ticker] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}]
Exception Location: {path}\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 881, in _resolve_lookup

Really appreciate your help on this Omar!

Comment: Wait I think I'd gotten confused. Just clarify one thing for me. This charts page of yours, it will always only display 4 charts at a time? What is the intended behavior? If someone navigates to the page without clicking on a ticker name, is it supposed to show all charts possible? Or will a user always have to pass a ticker to access that page?

Comment: Let me clarify one thing and a slight change. Each ETF ticker in my table has an Index ticker which is saved in my database and included in my models.py. In models.py, I now have `etf_ticker` and `index_ticker` The images contain index tickers in their filenames. If I click any row in my table, I want it to link to my charts.html page which should show 4 charts from my static/images folder, but ONLY the 4 charts which contain the ETF's index_ticker in the filename...NOT show all charts. The change I made to this question is I want to pass the index_ticker to URL to find image, not etf_ticker.

Comment: Okay. I'm going to modify my answer one more time. It seems all you need is a url that accepts a parameter. Your `ChartView` will always get a ticker

Comment: This results in the following exception error on the table.html page at the link: `<a href="{% url 'myapp:charts' i.index_ticker %}" target="_blank">`. 

Exception Value: Reverse for 'charts' not found. 'charts' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249312/discussion-between-omar-siddiqui-and-user16367225).